# Determine which face of a cube is facing the camera

Tags: unity, mathematics, camera, rotation

I have a Cube with a unique color for each face. I made a script where I can swipe and rotate the Cube in increments of 90 degrees in each direction. what's the best way to determine which face of a the Cube is facing the camera.

[image: My scene]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Iterating through the faces:**

```
faceNormal[i].dot(-worldViewVector) > 0.8 //(should actually be >0.9999)
```

**If you do an if/switch to apply a rotation to the cube(or camera):**
Just update and store a value indicating the front face at the same time.

This actually works the same for non-snapping angles such as your scene view. In the orthogonal mode, the dots just happen to be convenient, namely 1,0,0,0,0,-1, so the front face is obvious. Also consider that if you happen to find the back face first, the front face is the one opposite one; a little shortcut.

**If (-worldViewVector) is always (0,0,1) (toward the user)(camera fixed, cube rotates):**
You can just apply the inverse of the cube's rotation matrix to (0,0,1) and should end up with a unit direction vector indicating the front face (relative to the initial front face).
This modifies the iteration:

```
foreach(cube)
{
   thisCubesDirection = (0,0,1) * cube.RotationOnlyMatrix;
   if (thisCubesDirection.X > 0.999) ...
   else if ...
}
```

Comment: Cheers! Be sure to keep separate rotation-only matricies.